# Partial indentation after theorem

Tags: indentation

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum,amsthm,thmtools,xparse}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definizione}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xbegin}{mooo}
    {\IfValueTF{#4}
        {\begin{#1}[name={\contrel{#2}{#4}},continued={#3}]}
        {\IfValueTF{#3}
            {\begin{#1}[name={#2},label={#3}]}
            {\IfValueTF{#2}
                {\begin{#1}[name={#2}]}
                {\begin{#1}}
            }
        }
    }
\newcommand{\xend}[1]{\end{#1}\noindent}

\begin{document}
\xbegin{defi}
\lipsum[1]
\end{defi}
\lipsum[2]
\xbegin{defi}
\lipsum[3]
\xend{defi}
\lipsum[4]
\xbegin{defi}
\lipsum[5]
\end{defi}\noindent
\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
%5 and 1 comment. Then 6 more and 2 comment.
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Basically, `\xbegin` makes (to my eyes) the code for theorem starts more readable by giving the keys as optional arguments, without the `name=`, `label=` or `continues=` part. `\xend` *should* suppress the indent of the first line after the theorem. We notice the following:

1. After the first Definizione, we have that indent;
2. Curiously, if I use the normal `\begin`, I get no indent;
3. After the second Definizione, we get a partial indent, i.e. and indent by something between zero and the normal indent; it may seem like there is extra vertical space too, but it is just split pictures;
4. After the third Definizione, we get no indent.

So my questions are two:

1. Why does the indent appear with `\xbegin`, as noted in points 1-2?
2. Why does the `\noindent` in `\xend` only *partially* suppress the indentation?

Comment: `\noindent\ignorespaces` However, I can't see how a series of optional arguments can be better than a key-value interface. If you want to have `#4` only, you have to add two optional arguments and then test for their emptyness.

Comment: you are missing `%` from almost every line of your definition, but I would agree with egreg having two adjacent optional arguments is bad enough, I'd never do more than that.

Comment: OK, that removes the partial indent, which is in fact a space coming from the line end, which, after a `\noindent`, is turned into a space (right?). But why does the full indent appear with `\let\xend\end`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "partial indent" is not indentation it is just adjacent spaces coming from your source file, you need `%` at the ends of lines if you use white space to lay out your source that you do not want to appear in the output.

In comment you ask why you get full indent with `\let\xend\end` that is the normal behaviour for the start of a paragraph, which is the case after a theorem environment. Your `\xindent` suppresses the indentation but at the price of starting a new paragraph implicitly, which makes the markup very fragile, any space characters after the end of theorem environment will appear as space in the output, and a blank line or a display environment such as a list after the theorem environment would end the empty paragraph started by `\noindent` causing a spurious blank line,

Comment: That gives a reason to the cases when I had the extra vertical space (mostly when starting a thm right after another one), which I solved by using plain `\end` in those cases.

Comment: @MickG  never use `\noindent` in a macro:-)

Comment: Huh-huh, but typing it every time...

Comment: @MickG no if you use `\noindent` in the document then something is definitely wrong, it should be a document level style decision where paragraph indentation is needed.

Comment: @MickG look at latex sections and list items, they suppress indentation but never using `\noindent`

Comment: I usually do not modify `\parindent` to keep the indent for the first lines of proofs. Perhaps I should have my proof environment indent that line and then set `\parindent` to zero...

Comment: Anyway tomorrow I will take a look at how sections suppress the indentation.

Comment: proofs and theorems are usually set using \newtheorem  defined enviornments (which are one-item lists really) so have build in control over indentation (but this comment thread is getting too long and the system is cross with us:-)